# Failing Maven test JUnit5 test programmatically

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit5

I do execute my Maven tests with JUnit5, where all the test classes have the

```
@ExtendWith({ProcessExtension.class})
```

annotation. This extension must fail test methods according to a special logic in the if it is the case. But I have no idea how.

The method

```
@Override
public void afterEach(ExtensionContext context) {
    ...
}
```

gets this **context** parameter but the is no way to fail the already executed test method. How could I notify the Maven that the method has failed?

KI

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [`fail`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#fail-java.lang.String-) method for this:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;


public class ProcessExtension implements AfterEachCallback {

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        boolean failTest = ...;

        if (failTest) {
            fail("test failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's correct: you can fail a test within an `afterEach()` method simply by throwing an exception.